# Working workaround to set a zIndex KmlLayer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, z-index, settimeout

I've been searching for a straight solution to a problem I have since a couple of days.

For example , you need to add multiple kml layers on a map, in a specific order, then you need zIndex.

But with Google Maps API V3, you don't have such things.

Any idea?

Comment: What you need to do is re-format this whole thing.  Post just what's required to be a Question here.  Then post a separate Answer that solves the problem.

Comment: I just edited my post. The anwer will come later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things you can do.

First workaround is to add listeners:
https://gist.github.com/jkeefe/1170104

Second workaround is to set timeouts between calls.

It will not take long to load a layer on a map.

In fact, not more than 10 milliseconds is necessary.

Simply add setTimeout inside the callback function of a setTimeout.

Example:

```
    layers.setMap(map);
    setTimeout(function(){
       layers2.setMap(map);
       setTimeout(function(){
          layers3.setMap(map);
          setTimeout(function(){
             layers4.setMap(map);
             setTimeout(function(){
                layers5.setMap(map);         
             },400);      
          },100);
       },100);
   },100);
```

I used the second workaround.

If you think this thread is helpfull, then make me know,
Ciao!

Comment: This won't guarantee layer order (although it will be correct most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 [KmlLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerOptions) now includes `zIndex`.

From [the (latest) documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerOptions):

> zIndex | Type:  number
>
> The z-index of the layer.

(or you can use the [setZIndex](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/kml#KmlLayer.setZIndex) method)

See example in this related question: [KML ordering in Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455830/kml-ordering-in-google-maps-api)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mncpacrj/)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to guarantee order for Kml layers is to wait for previous layers to draw before adding the next layer. You listen to the `metadata_changed` event to know when a layer has drawn.

A z-index option is a highly requested feature: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2804

Comment: has z-index been implemeneted yet?